# How to name a thread and so that it appears in debug view in eclipse

Tags: android, multithreading, rename

How do i make something like this happen:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some of the constructors of the `Thread` class accept a `String` name. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: Not only that, but if you set the thread's name after creation (with `Thread#setName()`), the VM will forward the name change to DDMS.